# Delete square brackets with gsub does not work

Tags: r, string

I exported a list of coordinates which I want to import into R to use as an observation window.
The exported txt.file basically looks like this. The first row giving the x-coordinates, the second giving corresponding y-coordinates.

```
[9957.0, 7210.0, 11648.0, 17670.0, 15900.0, 12361.0, 12493.0, 10908.0]
[14734.0, 11141.0, 6598.0, 8500.0, 12277.0, 8606.0, 13730.0, 12911.0]
```

The imported R-Object looks like this:

```
    V1       V2     V3    V4    V5     V6    V7     V8
1  [9957.0   7210   11648 17670 15900  12361 12493  10908.0]
2  [14734.0  11141  6598  8500  12277  8606  13730  12911.0]
```

While importing the square brackets don't get removed. As I exported such windows for over a hundred data sets and likely will export even more of those I don't want to remove the square brackets manually.

But using

```
data <- gsub("\\[|\\]", "", data)
```

returns the following in R

```
[1] "2:1"             "c(7210, 11141)"  "c(11648, 6598)"  "c(17670, 8500)" 
[5] "c(15900, 12277)" "c(12361, 8606)"  "c(12493, 13730)" "1:2"
```

I don't understand what I did wrong to produce this behaviour. In the end I need a list of numeric x and y values.

Comment: I think you need to do this only on the first and last colun

Answer (score 0):

`gsub` expects a vector as input and not a data.frame.  Based on the data showed, the `[` and `]` are present in the first and last column.  So, select those columns, loop over them with `lapply` , then remove those brackets with `gsub` and assign it back

```
data[c(1, ncol(data))]<- lapply(data[c(1, ncol(data))],
     function(x) gsub("\\[|\\]", "", x))
```

NOTE: `lapply` is the standard method for looping data.frame columns so that if there are different types, it will be preserved

NOTE: This should be applied on the data that is read

```
 data <- read.table('yourfile.txt')
```

and not on the changed data showed in the OP's post

```
data <- gsub("\\[|\\]", "", data)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `gsub` in an `sapply`, and you may want to include the `,` in the delete pattern. `type.convert` will find automatically the right numeric format.

```
type.convert(sapply(d, gsub, pa="\\[|\\]|,", re=""))
#         V1    V2    V3    V4    V5    V6    V7    V8
# [1,]  9957  7210 11648 17670 15900 12361 12493 10908
# [2,] 14734 11141  6598  8500 12277  8606 13730 12911
```

Or in this special case with only zeroes after the decimal point you could do

```
type.convert(sapply(d, gsub, pa="\\D", re=""))/10
#         V1    V2    V3    V4    V5    V6    V7    V8
# [1,]  9957  7210 11648 17670 15900 12361 12493 10908
# [2,] 14734 11141  6598  8500 12277  8606 13730 12911
```

---

*Data:*

This presumably generates your data:

```
d <- read.table(text="[9957.0, 7210.0, 11648.0, 17670.0, 15900.0, 12361.0, 12493.0, 10908.0]
[14734.0, 11141.0, 6598.0, 8500.0, 12277.0, 8606.0, 13730.0, 12911.0]")
```